# Update a database record

Tags: vb.net, exception, datagridview

I use following code to update database record after retrieving data to the text boxes via a datagridview. 
But this gives me an exception as object reference not set to an instance of the object. Please help

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewUserType.CellClick
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridViewUserType.CurrentRow.Index
    If i >= 0 Then
        Me.txtBoxID.Text = DataGridViewUserType.Item(0, i).Value
        Me.txtBoxUserType.Text = DataGridViewUserType.Item(1, i).Value
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Empty Row Clicked")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnUserTypeUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUserTypeUpdate.Click
    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.User_Type SET Type = @tp WHERE  Type_ID = @ID"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtBoxID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tp", txtBoxUserType.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Updated")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & ex.Message, "Update Records")
    Finally
        con.Close()
        btnUserTypeSave.Show()
        txtBoxID.Clear()
        txtBoxUserType.Clear()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error message say which line, or have you been able to narrow down which object is causing this error? Try putting a messagebox in for both the txtBoxID and txtBoxUserType fields to see if they are available to the on click function

Comment: In which line that error showing?,

Comment: @Lima: I tried doing so and yes both text boxes are available to the click event n I cant find the line that error is referring to

Comment: remove `Try..Catch` blocks and you will get complete information about exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankz Fabio
The error was with "cmd"
I just put Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand before using it and now it is functioning.

Thankz All